# Jquery Mobile checkbox inserted and not showing theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile.
So I have a function which is called on a button click that creates checkboxes and inserts them into a div.
They show and function properly but are not themed with my button style like everything else in the project. If I just manually enter the html in the div. Then the styling is correct. But not if I insert them through jquery. What am I missing.

```
var html = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">';
        html += '<label for="radio-choice-01">First Name</label><input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-01" type="radio" data-theme="a">';
        html += '<label for="radio-choice-02">Second Name</label><input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-02" type="radio" data-theme="a">';
        html += '</fieldset>';
        $("#names_content").html(html);

$("input[name=namechoice]:radio").change(function(){
     var tempVal = $('input:radio:checked').val();
     alert("clicked");
     console.log(tempVal);
});
```

Comment: "If I just manually enter the html in the div then the styling is correct" ... can you please post this correct html/css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually enhace its markup:

```
$('[type="radio"]').checkboxradio();
```

Or use:

```
$("#names_content").trigger('create');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HPSCb/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
 var html = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">';
        html += '<label for="radio-choice-01">First Name</label><input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-01" type="radio" data-theme="a" checked="checked" value="1">';
        html += '<label for="radio-choice-02">Second Name</label><input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-02" type="radio" data-theme="a" value="2">';
        html += '</fieldset>';
        $("#names_content").html(html);      
        $("#names_content").trigger('create');

    $(document).on('change',"input[name=radio-choice-0]:radio",function(){
         var tempVal = $('input:radio:checked').val();
         alert(tempVal);
         console.log(tempVal);
    }); 
});
```

Every dynamically added content must be enhanced. There are several solutions and you can find them [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/).

Comment: Ugh! That was it! I'll give ya the answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: np m8 I am glad to help you :)

Comment: Both of your examples work great and they display. Now I just can't get the change event to fire. I have updated my first post to show the change event.

Comment: You need to bind it in a different way. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: That was it! I totally understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the lesson!